# Position absolute and fixed in a scrollable container

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable container, I want an image to be displayed in the middle on the bottom of the container, that will stay in the same place on the screen when I will scroll down. How should I do this? Right now I have something like this:

```css
    #container {
        height: 80vh;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0 !important;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #fixed {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-image: url('../images/img.png');
        width: 256px;
        height: 256px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      // scrollable content
      <div id="fixed">
      </div>
    </div>
```

But the image seems to be completely out of place. `Position: absolute` make the element disppear when I keep scrolling. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

Main changes to your draft: `min-height` of container: 100vh (full height of window), plus some details (`margin: 0;` on  `body`, `box-sizing: border-box;` on container, `bottom: 1px` on image div)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/256');
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  // scrollable content
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>blabla</p>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>blabla</p>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>blabla</p>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>blabla</p>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>blabla</p>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>blabla</p>
  <div id="fixed">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox layout.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2Lh3sLL/)**

```css
#container {
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#scroll {
  background: pink;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
#fixed {
  background: silver;
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="scroll">
    <div style="height: 200vh;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="fixed">
  </div>
</div>
```